# Office 2010 to Thunderbird migration

Tags: migration, microsoft-outlook-2010, import, thunderbird, pst

I've been reading a lot of things on the internet about this but can't get it to work. Also tried the Mozilla forums, did not get anything useful out of that.

What I could do is importing the PST files, but the plugin for that is outdated.. Which makes it a bit of a problem. I would also like to migrate all my account settings with this as well, I have 8 accounts running in outlook.

Does anyone know a simple way of doing this? And no, tools -> import doesn't work. Gives me errors, tried all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an IMAP server and convert your mail that way.

You can download some open-source ones that will install on your machine. (I used `dovecot` on my Mac, so I can't suggest any for Windows). Then very slowly (I do 50 at a time), you move your Outlook mail to an account you've set up on the IMAP server.

Then from Thunderbird, grab all those emails from the same IMAP account.

It preserves almost everything, including attachments. I found the compatibility far superior to any conversion or import / export methods.

Good luck. If you have a large PST file, you need a lot of patience but it's worth it in the end.

Comment: Thanks, did that just now. Worked like a charm. I didnt do it slowly, all at once and it worked heh.

Comment: Brave man. Then again, I had 6GB of PST to migrate :-)