# Migrating from Outlook (Win) to Thunderbird (Linux)

Tags: ubuntu, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, lightning, data-migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Office 2010 to Thunderbird migration](https://superuser.com/questions/195064/office-2010-to-thunderbird-migration)

My WinXP home computer recently got hit with some malware due to a browser vulnerability in Java Quick Start, and I finally decided to make the permanent switch to Linux (Ubuntu 10.04 LTS). Things have gone very well overall, but one difficulty has been migrating my personal email and addressbook data from Outlook 2007.

I installed Thunderbird 3.08 and set up my email accounts. However, the only information I can find online about migrating your email, address book, settings, etc. from Outlook assumes that you're running Thunderbird *under Windows*.

Has anyone gone from XP to Linux, and migrated their personal data from Outlook to Thunderbird (and calendar data to Lightning, for that matter)?

Did you have to install Thunderbird on Windows first, transfer the settings from Outlook into Thunderbird, then somehow use the Windows version of Thunderbird's data files with the Linux version...?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the method I suggested here:

[Office 2010 to Thunderbird migration](https://superuser.com/questions/195064/office-2010-to-thunderbird-migration/195141#195141)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks Randolph!  :-)

Comment: Glad it helped!